# What are the differences between saves in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What's the difference between "Quicksave", "Autosave" and a standard "save"?

Can I use the keybind to "Quicksave" instead of opening the menu to save the game every time I think its important?

Will I be able to "Load" the quick saved game just like any other?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Autosaves happen automatically according to your settings (On waiting, resting, fast traveling, changing location, or having the character menu open for a number of minutes). 3 autosaves are kept. Quicksaves are made on demand, and only 1 backup copy is kept. Regular saves are made on demand, and remain until you delete or overwrite them. Considering how many quest-breaking bugs there still are, you will likely regret not making a regular save every few hours.

You will always be able to load a save **that hasn't been overwritten**, which happens all the time to quick and autosaves. Unless it's corrupted, of course, which also happens not infrequently. Immediately reloading to a regular save you've made is recommended.

If you are on PC, using the `save "name"` console command can be immensely helpful. It is much easier to revert if your saves have meaningful names, rather than simply being numbered.

Comment: Brilliant explanation. Thanks for the console command, i will use it for sure

Comment: Every few hours? I keep about 10-15 saves going, and save every 5 minutes or so.

Comment: You save through the menu every 5 minutes, @AlanB? I admire your dedication, though it may be a good idea to keep at least a few saves that don't get overwritten every 50-75 minutes.